# Remove first 4 characters of a string with PHP

Tags: php, string, character

How can I remove the first 4 characters of a string using PHP?

Answer (score 524, accepted):

You could use the [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function to return a substring starting from the 5th character:

```
$str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
$str2 = substr($str, 4); // "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
```

Answer (score 28):

If you’re using a multi-byte character encoding and do not just want to remove the first four *bytes* like `substr` does, use the multi-byte counterpart [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/mb_substr). This does of course will also work with single-byte strings.