# How to remove the leading character from a string?

Tags: php, string, trim

I have a input string like:

```
$str = ':this is a applepie :) ';
```

How can I remove the first occurring `:` with PHP?

Desired output: `this is a applepie :)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Subtract First Character of String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592000/php-subtract-first-character-of-string)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove first 4 characters of a string php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286423/remove-first-4-characters-of-a-string-php)

Answer (score 357, accepted):

To remove every `:` from the beginning of a string, you can use [ltrim](http://php.net/ltrim):

```php
$str = '::f:o:';
$str = ltrim($str, ':');
var_dump($str); //=> 'f:o:'
```

Comment: Note that lrtim will remove all `:::::`. Sometimes this is not desired behavior.

Comment: note that this is only intended for single characters. ltrim will trim all of the characters in the provided string: `ltrim('prefixprefix_postfix', 'prefix')` results in `'_postfix';`

Comment: "How to remove the first character of string in PHP" was the question and this comment doesn't actually answer that.

Comment: Its replacing all when searching for "0" zero.

Answer (score 630):

The [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function will probably help you here:

```
 $str = substr($str, 1);
```

Strings are indexed starting from 0, and this functions second parameter takes the cutstart. So make that 1, and the first char is gone.

Comment: Be aware of unicode. If you're dealing with an arbitrary string (e.g. "Ål <- danish for eel"), you should use mb_substr and specify the encoding.

Comment: this is not a correct implementation, it not working with single character string "a". if you try single character string, substr return a boolean value

Comment: @anru The manual states if the string length is equal to the start parameter, an empty string will be returned. Prior to version 7, `false` was returned. So you would need to check if they're equal if that is not the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 99):

Use [substr](http://php.net/substr):

```
$str = substr($str, 1); // this is a applepie :)
```

Answer (score 71):

Exec time for the 3 answers :

Remove the first letter by replacing the case

```
$str = "hello";
$str[0] = "";
// $str[0] = false;
// $str[0] = null;
// replaced by �, but ok for echo
```

Exec time for 1.000.000 tests : `0.39602184295654` sec

---

Remove the first letter with substr()

```
$str = "hello";
$str = substr($str, 1);
```

Exec time for 1.000.000 tests : `5.153294801712` sec

---

Remove the first letter with ltrim()

```
$str = "hello";
$str= ltrim ($str,'h');
```

Exec time for 1.000.000 tests : `5.2393000125885` sec

---

Remove the first letter with preg_replace()

```
$str = "hello";
$str = preg_replace('/^./', '', $str);
```

Exec time for 1.000.000 tests : `6.8543920516968` sec

Comment: Thanks. See my update, though. It caused a problem for me when using the updated string in an SQL query.

Comment: I just tried the `$str[0] = '';` solution and it *didn't* work. well it does however if you then plan on using the variable for example to compare `>` or `<` it won't work. It still counts ` ` as +` for example

`$str = 'hello';
$str[0] = '';
var_dump($str); // string(5) 'ello'`

Comment: @Ian: I came across the same issue while fetching records from an API using a keyword, tried `var_dump($keyword)` which was showing the previous character length.. then I tried trimming the keyword and then it worked fine `var_dump(trim($keyword))`.. Hope this helps someone.. :)

Comment: This does not work. The "removed" position is replaced with null byte, so you get "\0hello" instead of "hello".

Comment: I get "Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset" for $str[0] = "";

Comment: Hi @Hayenn Could you show me how you do the speed tests for PHP functionalities?

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer:

```
$str = ltrim($str, ':');
```

works but will remove multiple `:` when there are more than one at the start.

```
$str = substr($str, 1);
```

will remove any character from the start.

However,

```
if ($str[0] === ':')
    $str = substr($str, 1);
```

works perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

## Update

After further tests, I don't recommend using this any more. It caused a problem for me when using the updated string in a MySQL query, and changing to `substr` fixed the problem. I thought about deleting this answer, but comments suggest it is quicker somehow so someone might have a use for it. You may find trimming the updated string resolves string length issues.

---

Sometimes you don't need a function:

```
$str[0] = '';
```

For example:

```
$str = 'AHello';
$str[0] = '';
echo $str; // 'Hello'
```

This method modifies the existing string rather than creating another.

Comment: This seems to be quicker too.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev how so? Just curious if you mean it's quicker to type or it runs quicker.

Comment: I mean that it runs more quickly.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev I'd be interested if you could provide some stats as I will add to the answer.

Comment: Gotta be careful with this. The code below outputs bool(false).

$foo = 'book';
$bar = 'book';
$bar = substr($bar, 1);
$foo[0] = '';
var_dump($foo === $bar);

Comment: why are they not equal?

Comment: @ina `gettype ()` might reveal why - I'm unable to test at the moment though

Comment: from a thread below - apparently it's a null byte so string comparison fails

Comment: This doesn't remove the first character.  It replaces it with a non printable `chr(0)`. It's equivalent to `$str[0] = chr(0);`. You can check the string code with `var_dump(bin2hex($str));` You will get `0048656c6c6f`. See that first `00` byte?

Comment: it's 17.61% faster then `substr($str, 1)`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work when you need to compare the results. https://3v4l.org/14Ekm#focus=7.4.16

Answer (score 8):

```
$str = substr($str, 1);
```

See [PHP manual example 3](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
echo substr('abcdef', 1);     // bcdef
```

Note:

```
unset($str[0])
```

*will not work* as you cannot unset part of a string:-

```
Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets
```

Answer (score 2):

use mb_substr function

```
    mb_substr("我abc", 1);
```

Comment: Useful if the character is a currency symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Trims occurrences of every word in an array from the beginning and end of a string + whitespace and optionally extra single characters as per normal trim()

```
<?php
function trim_words($what, $words, $char_list = '') {
    if(!is_array($words)) return false;
    $char_list .= " \t\n\r\0\x0B"; // default trim chars
    $pattern = "(".implode("|", array_map('preg_quote', $words)).")\b";
    $str = trim(preg_replace('~'.$pattern.'$~i', '', preg_replace('~^'.$pattern.'~i', '', trim($what, $char_list))), $char_list);
    return $str;
}

// for example:
$trim_list = array('AND', 'OR');

$what = ' OR x = 1 AND b = 2 AND ';
print_r(trim_words($what, $trim_list)); // => "x = 1 AND b = 2"

$what = ' ORDER BY x DESC, b ASC, ';
print_r(trim_words($what, $trim_list, ',')); // => "ORDER BY x DESC, b ASC"
?>
```

Comment: This answer seems to be completely ignoring the OP's question requirements and sample string.  This is, at most, the correct answer to a different question.

Answer (score -1):

The code works well for me.

```
$str = substr($str ,-(strlen($str)-1));
```

Maybe, contribute with answers too.

Comment: this one is not working with single character string: like "a"

Comment: You're right =)
So,  believe that a possible solution would be to test before it only contains one character.

For example:

$str = strlen($str) > 1 ? substr($str ,-(strlen($str)-1)) : $str;

Or 

$str = strlen($str) > 1 ? substr($str ,-(strlen($str)-1)) : '';   because the idea is to remove the last character, if you only have one ... :P