# PHP remove decimal from number string

Tags: php, decimal, eregi

i have an algorithym that gives back a number with a decimal point (I.E. ".57"). What I would like to do is just get the "57" without the decimal.

I have used eregi_replace and str_replace and neither worked!

```
$one = ".57";
$two = eregi_replace(".", "", $one);
print $two;
```

Comment: sorry, we will need more exact specifications about input and output...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the first character in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638569/how-to-remove-the-first-character-in-php)

Comment: Is the decimal point always at the beginning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$one = '.57';
$two = str_replace('.', '', $one);
echo $two;
```

That works.  100% tested.  BTW, all ereg(i)_* functions are depreciated.  Use preg_* instead if you need regex.

Answer (score 5):

```
Method       Result   Command
x100         57       ((float)$one * 100))
pow/strlen   57       ((float)$one * pow(10,(strlen($one)-1))))
substr       57       substr($one,1))
trim         57       ltrim($one,'.'))
str_replace  57       str_replace('.','',$one))
```

*Just shwoing some other methods of getting the same result*

Comment: Clever, but it wouldn't work if he got `.572`.  The result would be 57.

Comment: @Jonah: Fixed. Showed a few other alternatives, too.

Answer (score 2):

```
$number = ltrim($number, '.');
```

That removes all trailing dots.

Comment: Good, but we don't know if it's always on the (left) edge.  @Matthew is it?

Answer (score 1):

You say you've tried using str_replace without any luck, but the following code works perfectly:

```
<?php
    $one = '.57';
    $two = str_replace('.', '', $one);
    echo $two;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have used eregi_replace and str_replace and neither worked!

Well... [`ereg_replace()`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php) won't work cause it's using regular expresions, and `.` (dot) character has a special meaning: **everything** (so you've replaced every character into "" (the empty string)).

But [`str_replace()`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) works absolutely fine in this case.

Here's a live test: http://ideone.com/xKG7s

Answer (score 0):

This would return as an integer.

```
$two = (integer) trim('.', $one);
```