# How to prevent surplus comma at the beginning of a concatenated string

Tags: php, fizzbuzz

I am trying to solve the [FizzBuzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz) question in PHP (in this case using 'ApaBole' instead).

Counting from 1 to 100, numbers divisible by 3 should output 'Apa', numbers divisible by 5 should output 'Bole', and numbers divisible by both should output 'ApaBole'. All other numbers should output themselves.

**Desired Result**

> 1, 2, Apa, 4, Bole, Apa, 7, 8, Apa, Bole, 11, Apa, 13, 14, ApaBole, 16, 17, Apa, 19, Bole, Apa, 22, 23, Apa, Bole, 26, Apa, 28, 29, ApaBole, 31, 32, Apa, 34, Bole, Apa, 37, 38, Apa, Bole, 41, Apa, 43, 44, ApaBole, 46, 47, Apa, 49, Bole, Apa, 52, 53, Apa, Bole, 56, Apa, 58, 59, ApaBole, 61, 62, Apa, 64, Bole, Apa, 67, 68, Apa, Bole, 71, Apa, 73, 74, ApaBole, 76, 77, Apa, 79, Bole, Apa, 82, 83, Apa, Bole, 86, Apa, 88, 89, ApaBole, 91, 92, Apa, 94, Bole, Apa, 97, 98, Apa, Bole

**My Attempt**

```
for ($i= 1; $i <= 100; $i++)
{
    if($i % 15 == 0){
        echo ", ApaBole";
    } elseif($i % 3 == 0){
        echo ", Apa";
    } elseif($i % 5 == 0){
        echo ", Bole";
    } else{
        // rtrim($i, ", ");
        echo ', '.$i;
    }
}
```

**Output**

> , 1, 2, Apa, 4, Bole, Apa, 7, 8, Apa, Bole, 11, Apa, 13, 14, ApaBole, 16, 17, Apa, 19, Bole, Apa, 22, 23, Apa, Bole, 26, Apa, 28, 29, ApaBole, 31, 32, Apa, 34, Bole, Apa, 37, 38, Apa, Bole, 41, Apa, 43, 44, ApaBole, 46, 47, Apa, 49, Bole, Apa, 52, 53, Apa, Bole, 56, Apa, 58, 59, ApaBole, 61, 62, Apa, 64, Bole, Apa, 67, 68, Apa, Bole, 71, Apa, 73, 74, ApaBole, 76, 77, Apa, 79, Bole, Apa, 82, 83, Apa, Bole, 86, Apa, 88, 89, ApaBole, 91, 92, Apa, 94, Bole, Apa, 97, 98, Apa, Bole%

How do I remove the first `,` ?

Comment: you should not right a wrong, change your logic in `else` with `echo ($i !== 1) ? ', ' . $i : $i;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the first character of string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638569/how-to-remove-the-first-character-of-string-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few different ways you can achieve this. One being removing the first element in the string as suggested by @BadHorsie, but you can also use a check in the part that generates the first string, if you are at the first iteration or not.

```php
<?php

for ($i= 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    if ($i % 15 == 0) {
        echo ", ApaBole";
    } elseif ($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo ", Apa";
    } elseif ($i % 5 == 0) {
        echo ", Bole";
    } else {
        echo ($i == 1 ? '' : ', ').$i;
    }
}
```

- Demo at https://3v4l.org/FsKfp

Another way could be to store all the values in an array, and once you have all the values, `implode()` it with your desired delimiter.

```php
$values = [];
for ($i= 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    if ($i % 15 == 0) {
        $values[] = "ApaBole";
    } elseif ($i % 3 == 0) {
        $values[] = "Apa";
    } elseif ($i % 5 == 0) {
        $values[] = "Bole";
    } else {
        $values[] = $i;
    }
}
echo implode(", ", $values);
```

- Demo at https://3v4l.org/VPopV

Another could be to store all your values in a string-variable, then trim the first comma before you output it all.

```php
$output = '';
for ($i= 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    if ($i % 15 == 0) {
        $output .= ", ApaBole";
    } elseif ($i % 3 == 0) {
        $output .= ", Apa";
    } elseif ($i % 5 == 0) {
        $output .= ", Bole";
    } else {
        $output .= ', '.$i;
    }
}
echo ltrim($output, ', ');
```

- Demo at https://3v4l.org/QVYjZ

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve your result is to store the content in an array and then [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it :

```
$result = [];
for ($i= 1; $i <= 100; $i++)
{
    $temp = "";
    
    if($i % 3 == 0){
        $temp = "Apa";
    }
    
    if($i % 5 == 0){
        $temp .= "Bole"; // concate with previous value,
    }                    // if $i % 3 == 0 && $i % 5 == 0 then $i % 15 == 0
    
    if ($temp == "")
    {
        $temp = $i;
    }
    
    $result[] = $temp;
}

echo implode(", ", $result);
```

[Try it yourself](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5110ed8d9ed3689b2c8e620196d476e5f49bb656)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution to your question**

I see you're actually trying to solve the common FizzBuzz interview question, except yours is called 'ApaBole' as I'm guessing this is not English.

You could solve it neatly like so:

```
$output = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $output[] = ($i % 3 ? '' : 'Apa') . ($i % 5 ? '' : 'Bole') ?: $i;
}
echo implode(', ', $output);
```

By adding all the elements to an array, you can use [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join them all together with commas, without any stray leading or trailing commas added to the string.

---

**Additional notes about removing characters**

To answer your questions about general string manipulation in PHP, here are some pointers which will hopefully be helpful for your learning.

To get rid of the first character of a string, you just need to get a [substring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) starting at the second character.

```
$output = substr($input, 1);
```

However, it looks like you have a comma-separated list where you want to ensure there's no leading comma or 'empty' first item (you also have a space there). In which case, you might in fact want to trim off all commas/spaces at the start of the string, using [ltrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php).

```
$output = ltrim($input, ' ,');
```

If you want to ensure there's no commas or spaces at the start *or* end of your string, you can just use [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) instead.

```
$output = trim($input, ' ,');
```

In any case, it's better to improve your original code so that you don't have additional leading/trailing commas in the first place. This is exactly what the point of the interview question is - to see if you can properly craft a solution which doesn't leave mess like that.

Comment: I would also add a trim to it

Comment: @Kingalione Yep, I was just editing in a second option.

Comment: It's worth noting that OP is just `echo`ing the data rather than building a string.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to remove `,` at the creation of the string like :

```
<?php
for ($i= 1; $i <= 100; $i++)
{
    if($i % 15 == 0){
        echo ", ApaBole";
    } elseif($i % 3 == 0){
        echo ", Apa";
    } elseif($i % 5 == 0){
        echo ", Bole";
    } else{
        // rtrim($i, ", ");
        if($i == 1){
            echo $i;
        }else{
            echo ', '.$i;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de34ba2ec723ac96a08c1a81c1a82d8463cb1e9d

Answer (score 0):

One more approach using arrays:

```
<?php
$res = []; // create empty array
for ($i= 1; $i <= 100; $i++)
{
    if($i % 15 == 0){
        array_push($res, "ApaBole"); // push value into array
    } elseif($i % 3 == 0){
        array_push($res, "Apa"); // push value into array
    } elseif($i % 5 == 0){
        array_push($res, "Bole"); // push value into array
    } else {
        array_push($res, $i); // push value into array
    }
}

echo implode(',', $res); // implode array with commas
?>
```

[https://phpize.online/](https://phpize.online/?phpses=93b6f320a27530d17b4d71010a98013c&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

another compact code without `if`:

```
<?php
$res = [];
for ($i= 1; $i <= 100; $i++)
{
    array_push($res, (
        $i % 15 == 0 ? "ApaBole" : (
            $i % 3 == 0 ? "Apa" : (
                $i % 5 == 0 ? "Bole" : $i
            )
        )
    ));
}

echo implode(',', $res);
?>
```