# PHP: get every character of a string from 2nd character onwards

Tags: php, string, substring

Suppose I have the following string:

```
 $str = 2-Vsr2343xsf;
```

I know that the string starts with `2-`. I do not know the number of characters in a string.

I need to be able to take off `2-` off the start of the string so I am left with `Vsr2343xsf`

How can I achive this?

Comment: Please post what you have already tried.

Comment: substr, str_replace, explode, preg_replace all can be applied here

Comment: `$str = explode('-', '2-Vsr2343xsf')[1];` [If you are using a recent version of PHP](http://3v4l.org/mmaNG).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`substr`](http://php.net/substr). The first value is the string, the second is the starting character position (in your case, 2 is in position 0, the - is in position 1, etc.). You can also specify a length as a third parameter if you so choose.

```
$s = substr($str, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 2-Vsr2343xsf;
$str2 = substr($str, 2);
```

Using `substr()`. `$str2` in the required string.

See this:
[Remove first 4 characters of a string with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286423/remove-first-4-characters-of-a-string-php)