# php remove n chars from nth index of a string

Tags: php, substring

This question relates to an existing topic here..

[Remove first 4 characters of a string with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286423/remove-first-4-characters-of-a-string-php)

but instead what if i would like to remove specific number of characters from a specific index of a string?

e.g

```
(i want to remove 8 characters from the fourth index)
$input = 'asdqwe123jklzxc';
$output = 'asdlzxc';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$input = 'asdqwe123jklzxc';
echo str_replace(substr($input, 3, 8), '', $input);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Xzl6Yb)

Comment: This may replace more than intended if the string found by substr has more than one occurrence in $input. The answer by Hammurabi below is better in that case.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. It has a huge technical mistake as pointed out by @Oylex

Answer (score 8):

I think you need this:

`echo substr_replace($input, '', 3, 8);`

More information here:

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.substr-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
$output = substr($input, 0, 3) . substr($input, 11);
```

Where `0,3` in first `substr` are 4 letters in the beggining and `11` in second is `3+8`.

For better expirience you can wrap it with function:

```
function removePart($input, $start, $length) {
  return substr($input, 0, $start - 1) . substr($input, $start - 1 + $length);
}

$output = removePart($input, 4, 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try :

```
function substr_remove(&$input, $start, $length) {
    $subpart = substr($input, $start, $length);
    $input = substr_replace($input, '', $start, $length);
    return $subpart;
}
```